# Delete key is not working

Tags: android

I added setOnKeyListener for Enter keyevent. However, after I adding setOnKeyListener , delete (backspace) key is not working. When I removed the setOnKeyListener , delete key is working fine.

How to fix the delete key working well ?

```
final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {


            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 if (event != null&& (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

                     InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittext
                                .getApplicationWindowToken(),
                                InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

                     applySearch();


                 }
                return true;
            }


        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you return `True`, you are handling all the keys. Try this:

```
if (event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
    // something here
    return true;
}

// otherwhise
return false;
```

[Android: Problem with overriding onKeyListener for a Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853200/android-problem-with-overriding-onkeylistener-for-a-button)

Comment: Thanks! My problem was that delete stopped working after switching keyboard language although I override only enter key. Also the problem didn't show up on android 8 but was there for earlier versions. You saved me time!

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html) `onKey` returns `True` if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise. In your case:

```
@Override
public boolean onKey(View arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent event) {
    ...
    return true; // Try to return false instead
}
```

When your method returns `true` keys aren't processed and backspace doesn't work.